# SQL Update single column depending on conditions of multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2016, I have 2 tables (Del_Test_Main and Del_Test_Stg) Later will always get the latest list of Active Id's based on which I want to update the main table.

But there are multiple scenarios:

- If the main table has an Id that does not exist in the Stg table, then Update IsDelete column of the main table to 1 and update Rootpid only for those rows.
- If the main table has an Id that also exists in Stg table, but IsDelete column value is 1 in the Main table then Update IsDelete column to 0 and update Rootpid only for those rows.

Input Query:

```
Create table Del_Test_Main
(
uniqueId bigint identity not null,
Id int,
Name varchar(50),
IsDelete tinyint default 0,
RootPid varchar(50)
)


insert into  Del_Test_Main (Id,Name,IsDelete,RootPid) values (1,'Vj',0,'20190101') , 
(2,'john',0,'20190101'), (3,'lance',1,'20190101' ), (4,'kate',1,'20190101' )



Create table Del_Test_Stg
(

Id int
)

insert into Del_Test_Stg (Id) values (1) ,(3)


select * from Del_Test_Main
select Id as ActiveIds from Del_Test_Stg
```

Using below update queries I can achieve expected results. But how can I get it done in a single update query for both Scenarios? Also, the count of Id's will be in thousands and millions so also need to consider about the query from a performance perspective.

```
-- S1
SELECT main.Id AS "List_Of_Ids_to_Update_in_main_AS_1" 
--UPDATE main 
--SET IsDelete = 1, RootPid = '20190202' 
FROM ..Del_Test_Main main
 LEFT JOIN .. Del_Test_Stg del
 ON main.Id=del.Id
 WHERE del.Id IS NULL  
 AND main.IsDelete = 0 


 -- S2
 SELECT main.Id AS "List_Of_Ids_to_Update_in_main_AS_0"  
 --UPDATE main 
--SET IsDelete = 0, RootPid = '20190202'  
FROM ..Del_Test_Main main
INNER JOIN ..Del_Test_Stg del
ON main.Id=del.Id 
WHERE main.IsDelete = 1
```

UPDATE:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Case Statement

```
SELECT main.*, del.*,
    Case when  del.Id IS NULL then 'List_Of_Ids_to_Update_in_main_AS_0'  
        when main.IsDelete = 1 and del.Id IS NOT NULL then 'List_Of_Ids_to_Update_in_main_AS_1' 
        Else 'Both Exists and main.IsDelete = 0'End 
    AS mainId  
--UPDATE main 
--SET IsDelete = Case when main.IsDelete = 1 and del.Id IS NULL then 0
--          when main.IsDelete = 0 and del.Id IS NOT NULL then 1 End,
--          Else IsDelete End,
--  RootPid = '20190202'  
FROM ..Del_Test_Main main
LEFT JOIN ..Del_Test_Stg del
ON main.Id=del.Id 
WHERE main.IsDelete = 1 or main.IsDelete = 0
```

**With your output edit, I changed my query**

```
SELECT main.*, del.*,
    Case when del.Id IS NULL And main.IsDelete = 0  then 'Change IsDelete to 1'  
        when main.IsDelete = 1 and del.Id IS NOT NULL then 'Change IsDelete to 0' 
        Else 'Keep IsDelete as it is  ' End 
    AS mainId,  
    Case when  del.Id IS NULL And main.IsDelete = 0 then 'Change RootPid to 20190202' 
        When main.IsDelete = 1 and del.Id IS NOT NULL then 'Change RootPid to 20190202'
        Else 'Keep RootPid as it is  ' End 
    AS RootPid 
--UPDATE main 
--SET IsDelete = Case when del.Id IS NULL And main.IsDelete = 0  then 1
--          when main.IsDelete = 1 and del.Id IS NOT NULL then 0 
--          Else IsDelete End,
--      RootPid = Case when del.Id IS NULL And main.IsDelete = 0  then '20190202'
--          when main.IsDelete = 1 and del.Id IS NOT NULL then '20190202' 
--          Else RootPid End
    FROM ..Del_Test_Main main
    LEFT JOIN ..Del_Test_Stg del
    ON main.Id=del.Id
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cb7c18c21ca13694539cb9f2bc094813)

Comment: thanks, but your query is not giving expected output. Please Check my post I have added the expected result.

Comment: @VikasJ, now check please

Comment: Thanks @Srinika Pinnaduwage

Answer (score 1):

You can use below simple queries,

1. Updates IsDelete to 0 in Del_Test_Main when there is no id in Del_Test_Stg table

   ```
   update Del_Test_Main set IsDelete = 0 where id not in
   (select id from Del_Test_Stg);
   ```
2. Updates IsDelete to 1 when there is id in Del_Test_Stg table and IsDelete is 0 in Del_Test_Main table

   ```
   update Del_Test_Main set IsDelete = 1 where IsDelete  = 0 and id in
   (select id from Del_Test_Stg);
   ```
3. Both the operations in one query,

   ```
   update Del_Test_Main
   set IsDelete = case when id not in (select id from Del_Test_Stg) then 0
               when id in (select id from Del_Test_Stg) and IsDelete = 0 
   then 1 end;
   ```

Comment: As I have mentioned in my post, I don't want 2 update queries, I want it to be done using 1 update query for both scenarios to match expected output

Comment: In that case you can use case statement, provided above

Comment: Yes, But that's still not giving expected output. It updating all rows. What I want is in single query it should update only expected rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a `left join` and a `case` expression:

```
update m
    set isdelete = (case when s.id is null then 1
                         when s.id is not null and m.isDelete = 1 then 0
                         else isdelete
                    end)
from del_test_main m left join
     del_test_stg s
     on m.id = s.id
where s.id is null or s.id is not null and m.isDelete = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c12500d4623000d0eb6693706c93b947) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thanks, but your query is not giving expected output. Please Check my post I have added the expected result.

Comment: @VikasJ . . . Your sample data explains better what you want to do.  I modified the answer.